# react-datepicker time column displaying under calendar

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I'm having an issue with the `react-datepicker` component. Here is my code:

```
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

<DatePicker
  selected={values.date}
  onChange={(value): void => setFieldValue('date', value.getTime())}
  className="form-control"
  wrapperClassName="w-100"
  showTimeSelect
  timeFormat="HH:mm"
  timeIntervals={60}
  timeCaption="time"
  dateFormat="MMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
/>
```

Here's how it is displayed:

[image]

Comment: Maybe related to the custom styles? wrapperClassname?

Comment: Tried setting wrapperClassName, popperClassName, and className to d-flex, no success.

Answer (score 1):

could still help someone : I solved this issue with

```html
<div id="DP-wrapping-div">
    <DatePicker
       portalId="DP-wrapping-div"
       ...
    />
</div>
```